# C++ HW - how odes this compile?

Tags: arrays, indexing

I've studying C++ for only a while and I came upon this problem, I figured it out but I'm not so sure as to why this makes sense.

I tried writing an if statement within the for loop but failed to get the desired results. I tried to implement the if statement down below within the for loop and it didn't have the same results.
My question is, does the if statement create a new index for bonusScores[SCORES_SIZE]?

Challenge Activity:
Write a loop that sets each array element to the sum of itself and the next element, except for the last element which stays the same. Be careful not to index beyond the last element. Ex:

Initial scores:        10, 20, 30, 40
Scores after the loop: 30, 50, 70, 40

The first element is 30 or 10 + 20, the second element is 50 or 20 + 30, and the third element is 70 or 30 + 40. The last element remains the same.

There are three tested inputs:

10, 20, 30, 40
199, 99, 9, 0
-100, -200, -300, -400

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
       const int SCORES_SIZE = 4;
       int bonusScores[SCORES_SIZE];
       int i;

       for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; ++i) {
          cin >> bonusScores[i];
       }

       if (bonusScores[i] = bonusScores[SCORES_SIZE]) {
          bonusScores[i] = 0;
       }

       for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; ++i)   {
          bonusScores[i] = bonusScores[i] + bonusScores[i + 1];
       }

       for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; ++i) {
          cout << bonusScores[i] << " ";
       }
       cout << endl;

       return 0;
    }
```

I tried implementing an if statement within the for loop but didn't know how to get the results needed.
I tried an if statement outside of the for loop before and after and managed to get the proper results with an if statement before the for loop. I'm guessing I may have created additional index for bonusScores[i + 1], but technically there shouldn't be an index of [4] since the highest in the given array should be [3]

Comment: = is not == and that seems to be a central bug here